# how to access to an object between whole Activities in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

My problem is that my two Activities `GameActivity` and `StoreActivity` should share same `Player`, and every change in `Player` made in any `Activity` should be seen in all Activities, but when I buy `Upgrade` in `StoreActivity` and change from `StoreActivity` the state of object is from before purchase.`Player` is `Serializable`.

`OnClickListener` from `StoreActivity`:

```
        LIST_VIEW.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Upgrade upgrade = (Upgrade)LIST_VIEW.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                if(upgrade.getCost() > player.getMoney()) {
                    LIST_VIEW.getChildAt(position).setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    player.buyUpgrade(upgrade);
                    CURRENT_MONEY.setText(getString(R.string.current_money) + player.getMoney());
                 //Notify GameActivity, but how?
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the flow of the activities? there are several option like LocalBroadCastReceiver, SharedPreference, OnActivityResult... depends on flow.does on click listener redirect to GameActivity?

Answer (score 0):

The `android.app.Activity` class has an `onResume()` method.

It will be called when an activity is back interacting with the user.

So perfectly for your use case, because when the user wants to return, `GameActivity` will be unpaused and`onResume()` gets called.

You can implement it like this:

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            //refreshing changed list items
        }
}
```

Comment: Not really. `onResume()` is called also when I start game, so it gives me `NullPointerException` because I try to fetch my player instance from `StoreActivity` even before I entered `StoreActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You can tie your `Player` object to the app lifecycle by extending your `Application` class and storing your instance there. It would allow you to have a reference for it on every Activity without leaking during it's lifecycles. You can check for it's value and show some loading and create an callback for when it is set, so all activities can be notified about.

This great [Codepath article](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class) explains how to do it.

Your main Application could look like this:

```java
public class MyCustomApplication extends Application {
  private Player player;
  private ArrayList<WeakReference<OnPlayerSetCallback>> callbacks;

  public void addCallback(WeakReference<OnPlayerSetCallback> callbackRef) {
    this.callbacks.add(callbackRef);
  }

  public void removeCallback(WeakReference<OnPlayerSetCallback> callbackRef) {
    this.callback.remove(callbackRef);
  }

  public void setPlayer(Player player) {
    this.player = player;

    for (WeakReference<OnPlayerSetCallback> callbackRef : callbacks) {
      OnPlayerSetCallback callback = callbackRef.get();
      if (callback == null) {
        // remove invalid callback references (if an activity was destroyed, for example)
        callbacks.remove(callbackRef);
      } else {
        // notify activities that a player was set
        callback.onPlayerSet(player);
      }
    }
  }

  public Player getPlayer() {
    return this.player;
  }

  interface OnPlayerSetCallback {
    Player onPlayerSet();
  }
}
```

Updating your Player shouldn't be a problem, as every activity would be using the same instance. However, if you need to update UI without having any lifecycle to re-render it in between, you can create an update listener in the callback.

Comment: Update: I believe the best way to share data between activities today is using a [View Model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). It's far more elegant than the approach I described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Singleton** design Pattern.

You create one object from **PlayerRepository** with **player** field and in your app you just get it and each time
you want you change it.

```
    public class PlayerRepository {

    private Player player;

    private static final PlayerRepository ourInstance = new PlayerRepository();

    public static PlayerRepository getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private PlayerRepository() {
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player player)
    {
        this.player=player;
    }
    public Player getPlayer()
    {
        retrun this.player;
    }
}
```

In your Activities

```
PlayerRepository playerRepository=PlayerRepository.getInstance();
Player player=playerRepository.getPlayer();
player.buyUpgrade(upgrade);
```

Comment: maybe it helps you [Singleton pattern in Java](https://tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm)